# Figuring out probability of dice with least amount of questions

Tags: probability, dice

> Given $n$ dice, each with $k$ faces numbered $1,\dots,k$, you're allowed to ask me what the probability of some event happening is (a subset of all the possibilities and I give a number).
>
> What is the least amount of questions you can ask in order to figure out what the probability for each die to be $i$ for all $i=1,\dots,k$.

If I further restrict myself so that each die has a rational probability for any number, can the above be improved?

Comment: I think you mean dice. A cube by definition has $6$ faces.

Comment: "figure it out" -- figure what out? The probabilities of the individual faces appearing?

Comment: You may need to make it more clear.

Comment: @joriki Yes, updated.

Comment: @user336-iactuallychosethis,  I still don't understand the question. may you provide us the answer for $k=2$ or $k=3$ for example (if you can calculate this case)?

Comment: @d_e joriki explains his interpertatino which is correct and is by far better than any explanation I'll be able to provide (check out his answer). Sorry for being bad at formulating my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret the question as follows: The dice are not fair, and they may be different; we want to determine the probabilities $p_{ij}$ of all $k$ faces of all $n$ dice by asking a minimal number of questions about the probability of events that may occur when we throw all $n$ dice.

Obviously we can do with $n(k-1)$ questions by going through $k-1$ faces for each die and using the normalisation condition for the $k$-th face. In special cases we may do better, e.g. if a die is certain to always show a particular face, but in the general case, we can't do better than $n(k-1)$ questions, since the space of possible probabilities is an $n(k-1)$-dimensional manifold and each answer yields an algebraic equation in the $n(k-1)$ unknowns that reduces the dimension of the manifold by $1$.

The case of rational probabilities seems more complicated; my guess would be that this doesn't help, but I wouldn't know how to prove it.

Comment: In what course would one learn about the manifold? The equations we get seem complicated to me (I mean it's different than regular linear algebra equtations) so I don't quite understand what's going on.

Comment: @user336-iactuallychosethis: I don't know much about the structure of courses, but I'd imagine that it would be treated in courses on differential geometry and/or topology.

Comment: BTW does your answer work if they don't have the same number of faces?

Comment: @user336-iactuallychosethis: Yes, no change there.